# This rawquery is possible: WHERE (column a * column a / '" +double+ "_%') BETWEEN 'int' AND 'int'

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

What I want to realize is: 
inside the WHERE of introducing a multiplication and a division. 
It is possible.

CODE:

```
public int estadistica_peso_actual_n (String s_actual_ano, Double d_altura) {
String s_est = "SELECT COUNT(tr_peso)*100 / (SELECT COUNT(tr_peso) FROM bdt_registro WHERE tr_fecha LIKE '" +s_actual_ano+ "_%') AS porcentaje FROM bdt_registro WHERE (tr_peso*tr_peso/'" +d_altura+ "_%') BETWEEN '20' AND '24' AND tr_fecha LIKE '" +s_actual_ano+ "_%'";
Cursor c_est = db.rawQuery(s_est, null);
int i_peso_n = 0;
if (c_est.moveToLast()) { 
    i_peso_n = c_est.getInt (c_est.getColumnIndex("porcentaje"));
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "peso" + i_peso_n);
}
c_est.close();
return i_peso_n;                            
}
```

This code returns zero.
I like that was returning between 20 and 24.

Thank you for the showed interest.

Comment: What is the meaning of `... tr_peso/'" +d_altura+ "_%'`? You cannot divide by a string.

Comment: thanks for replying but tr_peso in the database is number.

Comment: Sorry the code was bad. new code: ... WHERE (tr_peso/'" +d_altura+ "') BETWEEN ...

Comment: I am sorry. the code was bad written. Thanks to all for the showed interest

Comment: good code: "SELECT COUNT(tr_peso)*100 / (SELECT COUNT(tr_peso) FROM bdt_registro WHERE tr_peso LIKE '_%' AND tr_fecha LIKE '" +s_actual_ano+ "_%') AS porcentaje FROM bdt_registro WHERE (tr_peso/'" +d_altura+ "') BETWEEN 20 AND 24 AND tr_fecha LIKE '" +s_actual_ano+ "_%'";

Answer (score 0):

Replace `BETWEEN '20' AND '24'` with `BETWEEN 20 AND 24`.

You are actually comparing `NUMERIC` data with `TEXT` data.